# Plot a graph with a hole in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

I would like to emphasize graphs with holes in Wolfram alpha, so I've tried graphing a rational function with a hole. However, the graph that WA is generating isn't showing the hole. Is there a way to emphasize the hole in WA?

Thanks

Comment: Umm... If you graph a function without a hole, how can WolframAlpha show you a hole in the graph?

Comment: Good catch. Sorry, I meant with a hole

Comment: The function I tried graphing is y=(x^2 -1)/(x -1)